# How to use timeshift effectively on Ubuntu?

Tags: backup, restore

What settings should i have to create

1. a backup of the OS and Media including stuff installed via apt/snap etc?
2. a backup of only my Media?
3. a backup of only the OS including stuff installed via apt/snap etc?
4. a backup of only the OS?

ran into an [issue](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/400) which hasnt been answered yet so i figured here is the next best place

Comment: no it isn't, used a ppa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Full File System Snaphots including OS, Media and installed staff: **Settings** -> **Users** and switch radio-button under **Include All**; **Settings** -> **Filters** remove all filters.
2. Go to **Settings** -> **Users** Tab and switch radio-button under **Include All** then go **Settings** -> **Filters** and add patterns to exclude all another dirs from your File System.
3. , 4. Go to **Settings** -> **Filters** Tab and use needed patterns to exclude unnecessary staff.